# PySolr connection error 404

Tags: python, solr, pysolr

I am using solrv5.0 and pysolr but I get the following traceback when I run a python script:

```
File "site-packages/pysolr.py", line 322, in _send_request
raise SolrError(error_message)
pysolr.SolrError: [Reason: Error 404 Not Found
```

For the script lines about pySolr, I only have:

```
solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/', timeout=10)
solr.add([dict])
```

where dict is a python dictionnary.
When I comment  # solr.add, I haven't got any errors.
So I think I get the connection but I can't update... Why?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Open `site-packages/pysolr.py` as read-only in a text editor, go to line 322, and see which file `_send_request()` is trying to use. May give you a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: I have this:if int(resp.status_code) != 200:
            error_message = self._extract_error(resp)
            self.log.error(error_message, extra={'data': {'headers': resp.headers,
                                                          'response': resp.content}})
            raise SolrError(error_message)

Comment: Sorry for the bad comment above, it has been edited too much quickly. But this don't give me a nudge for this error... I think.

Comment: Look at the lines prior to `if int(resp.status_code) != 200` which causes the `if` stanza to be activated. These lines should tell you which file failed to be found, causing the 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to specify my **solr core** to get this command to work.

This:

`solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/', timeout=10)`

Should be:

`solr = pysolr.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/your_core_name', timeout=10)`

Comment: From where can i get the core_name?

Comment: This is the name of your index: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/solr-cores-and-solr-xml.html